# How to assign Multiple roles to a single user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, roles, role

I want to make a plugin which can assign multiple roles to a single user. Some say its not possible to assign multiple roles in wordpress then why wordpress has provided 'roles' in array form.
e.g when i call roles of user it returns array

```
$current_user=wp_get_current_user();
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
```

here $user_roles will be an array return by roles.

Is there any function through which i can assign multiple role to a single user

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134656/assign-multiple-roles-overlapping-capabilities

Comment: Hey Suyog i saw the referred page but there too i didn't get how can i add multiple roles to a single user

Comment: Have you tried https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#add_role.28_.24role_.29 You should be able to use `$current_user->add_role('role_name');`

Comment: Hey Tristan..thanxx it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All thanks to tristan, finally i assigned multiple role to a single user.This code helped me to achieve that.

```
 $addMemberToGroup = new WP_User($required_id);
 $addMemberToGroup->add_role( $role );
```

here $required_id is the id of user whom i want to assign role.